# How to dynamically add a 'body' tag to the document if it doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser

I'm trying to add a body to a page if it doesn't exist. But the following throws a DOMException

```
> document.appendChild(document.createElement('body'))

DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Nodes of type 'BODY' may not be inserted inside nodes of type '#document'.
```

Same thing happens if I try to insert an html tag. I'm using chrome at the moment.

Comment: Yeah, that's the same question as mine. The answer there, however, doesn't work for me.

Comment: Update: got it to work after some modification

Comment: Answer yourself here then, it may be useful for someone else.